# Combined Box Shadow Transition and Border Transition not working.

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a textarea and on focus I would like to animate both Border Shadow and Border Radius, the problem is if I try to combine those two together Border Radius animation does not work it just "Pops Out" without any animation. I have created a [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZN54h/) to show you my problem.

Code looks like this:

```
textarea{   
display: block;
padding-left: 3px;
padding-right: 3px;
border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;  
box-shadow: 0 0 3px #e7e7e7;
background: none;
color: #6b6b6b;
max-width: 100%;
}

textarea:focus {
outline: none;  
box-shadow: 0 0 25px #9ecaed;
-webkit-transition: box-shadow linear 1s;
transition: box-shadow linear 1s;

border-color: #9ecaed;
 transition : border 500ms ease-out; 
-webkit-transition : border 500ms ease-out; 
-moz-transition : border 500ms ease-out;
-o-transition : border 500ms ease-out;    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS doesn't work the way you're expecting it to.

After setting `transition: box-shadow linear 1s;` you are **overriding** it with `transition : border 500ms ease-out;`. You have to set them **both** on the same property.

Like so ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaypeagi/ZN54h/1/)):

```
textarea:focus {
    outline: none;  
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px #9ecaed;
    border-color: #9ecaed;

    transition: box-shadow linear 1, border 500ms ease-out; 
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow linear 1, border 500ms ease-out; 
    -moz-transition: box-shadow linear 1, border 500ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: box-shadow linear 1, border 500ms ease-out;    
}
```